# White space after wrap text in HTML

Tags: html, css, whitespace

[image]

As you can see, there is a right white space. This is my code:

```
<style>
    div {
        width: 480px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    html,body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Please help me remove it. Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change div's `width` value from `480px` to `100%`:

So... change this:

```
width: 480px;
```

on this:

```
width: 100%;
```

But, if You want to center this `<div>` with Your content, just add following to `div` CSS selector:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<STYLE>div{width:100%;word-wrap:break-word;} html,body{margin:0;padding:0;}</STYLE>
```

This should be all